# Should I standardize questionnaire responses prior to reliability analysis?

Tags: correlation, spss, survey, reliability

I have a multiple questionnaires with responses on Likert scales. They differ in that some are rated on a 7p scale, and others on a 5p scale. I would like to look at the reliability of each scale as well as the correlation between scales (and sub-scales).

By standardization I mean computing the z-score (subtract mean, divide by standard deviation), or should I merely normalize the range (scale every item to $[0,1]$), for better comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely want to put the 5 and 7 point scale items onto some sort of a common range if you're trying to combine them into a single scale and assess reliability. The SPSS RELIABILITY procedure will actually produce both "raw" alpha based on variances and covariances, as well as a standardized item alpha based on correlations with standard unit variances if you do anything to invoke the construction of a covariance matrix. This can be done directly in command syntax by including

/METHOD=COVARIANCE

or in the dialogs by asking for any of a variety of statistics, including a covariance or correlation matrix.